# How to get text from element without whitespace normalization and trimmed using SwiftSoup in swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, iphone, swiftsoup

I want to get exact text without whitespace normalisation and trim using SwiftSoup library.

Currently,
SwiftSoup provide element.text() method to extract text from that element.

But text()- Method gives trimmed and whitespace normalised text.

Any other way to get element text without trimmed and whitespace normalised?

Comment: did you try .html() ?
This would get all inner elements as well though, if there are any

Answer (score 0):

This is not SwiftSoup specific but should be correct for the HTML DOM and is probably similar here:

> The innerText property returns just the text, without spacing and
> inner element tags.
>  The innerHTML property returns the text, including
> all spacing and inner element tags.
>  The textContent property returns
> the text with spacing, but without inner element tags.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp

Not sure how to access the `textContent` property with SwiftSoup (if that exists) but that's probably what you want.
 In case `.html()` doesn't work for you.